# Stars in star clusters in SMC and LMC

Tags: star, star-cluster, cepheids, dwarf-galaxy, magellanic-cloud

Is there any catalog or any paper published in any journal that lists the stars discovered under whichever star cluster of the Small Magellanic Cloud (SMC) they belong to? There is one for Large Magellanic Cloud (LMC) in the paper Efremov 2003 "Cepheids in LMC clusters and the period-age relation". But I can't find any for SMC.

It would be better still if the stars happen to be Cepheids.

Comment: Did you already look in arXiv?

Comment: Yup. tried the arXiv already. But failed. I came here after trying everything I could, I guess.

Comment: Do you mean (by "failed"): you didn't find any papers at all about this topic, or you didn't find the exact information you are looking for?

Comment: I found the list of star clusters. But I am searching for the list of stars in each of the star cluster. That I failed to find. Either it doesn't exist or I wasn't great at searching.

Comment: please, add the links of these papers in your original post: they could help much more in answering your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after searching quite a deal, I found [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9912190) paper which would aptly answer the question.

The paper from 1999 published by Pietrzynski and Udalski in Acta Astronomica lists the Cepheids in the star clusters of Magellanic Clouds.

Answer (score 1):

Vizier is a good resource for finding catalogs. Searching for "SMC+cepheid" I found a related paper (Udalski et al. 1999) with additional data http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR?-source=J/AcA/49/437. You can also look for "Similar Catalogs" though it may or may not be useful in this case.

Comment: This was the same paper that is referred to in the already extant answer.